# Junit4+Robolectric: Marking outer class as test case and run it

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, robolectric

I have a class with a nested class, which contains test case. It looks like this:

```
public class ProviderUtilsTest {
        public static final String TAG = ProviderUtilsTest.class.getSimpleName();

        public static class TestConstructor {

            @Test
            public void noPublicConstructor() {
                Class<ProviderUtils> clazz = ProviderUtils.class;
                Constructor<?>[] constructors = clazz.getConstructors();
                for (Constructor<?> constructor : constructors) {
                    assertThat(constructor.isAccessible(), is(false));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I use this configuration Android Studio doesn't treat `ProviderUtilsTest` as a test case. I.e. it doesn't allow to run it when I click on its file with RMB and it doesn't display run button on the left of the class declaration line. But it displays it for nested class.

How can I make it treat the `ProviderUtilsTest` as a test case i.e. display an appropriate UI alements and force it to run all tests of the nested classes?

Comment: Why do you want to put tests in nested classes?

Comment: For the better structure purposes. I want the outer class to represent the test case for the whole class, each nested class a test case for aprticular method, each method of nested class to be a test for specific input.

Comment: I doubt that this is a good approach. If you nest the classes purely for structure, think about using packages, subpackages and naming conventions. Furthermore you can write helper classes that gather initialization logic if you don't want to duplicate such things.

Comment: To test the package visible methods I need to put all the test cases in the same package. Considering this and that fact that I want tests for a method to be in a separate class - the package is going to grow very fast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to say how bad your implementation of good test idea is, but I would provide you my solution, which should work and give the same result as yours.

Change your existing code to:

```
public class ProviderUtilsTest {
        public static final String TAG = ProviderUtilsTest.class.getSimpleName();

        public static class TestConstructor {

            public boolean noPublicConstructor() {
                Class<ProviderUtils> clazz = ProviderUtils.class;
                Constructor<?>[] constructors = clazz.getConstructors();
                for (Constructor<?> constructor : constructors) {
                    if (constructor.isAccessible()) return false;
                }
                return true
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in your ExampleActivityTest write this:

```
 @Test
 public void ensureThatThereIsNoPublicConstructor() throws Exception {
    assertTrue(ProviderUtilsTest.TestConstructor.noPublicConstructor());
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Why is my implementation bad?

Comment: JF Meier said about it. Check my answer

Comment: Oh, so you're talking only about the way I want to organize the tests not about the implementation of a particular test (check fo the absence of public constructor)?

Comment: You cannot get Junit test from an outer static class. I give an example how you can ommit this problem changing from test method to `function` and calling it in test class

Answer (score 0):

> For the better structure purposes. I want the outer class to represent the test case for the whole class, each nested class a test case for aprticular method, each method of nested class to be a test for specific input

Alternatively, you can use packages to organize your test cases.

Comment: I need to put test cases in the same package as the class under testing. Which means that test package will grow very quickly if I want to have a separate class for all tests of a single method.

Comment: "I need to put test cases in the same package as the class under testing." What are your reasons for this? Are you testing package-private methods?

Comment: Yes. We have some helper methods within many classes which are marked as @VisibleForTesting and made package private.